# Eagle PCB: how to get BOM from a library part?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad

I am using a library part in my Eagle PCB schematic. I would love to learn more about what's inside / what sub-components the library owner used to make it. Is there any way to do this? For example without the internal parts list I have no idea how to estimate the cost.

I tried the `run bom.ulp` command which didn't work (it only showed the top-level module as being a part in the BOM).

Here is the library in particular I've imported: http://forum.pjrc.com/threads/935-Eagle-library-with-Teensy-3-0-footprint?p=20178&viewfull=1#post20178

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got is a footprint for a teensy connector. There is no information in that about the teensy itself.

Comment: What does this mean and how should I proceed?

Comment: Towards what end? If you want information about the teensy itself I'm sure you can find that by googling.

Comment: Sorry let me be more specific. Can I take this library part and fabricate a teensy board with it and extend, e.g. connecting a sensor to a GPIO? I was concerned that since I wasn't able to generate a BOM I might not be able to use it for my design

Comment: From the discussion you got it from I read that this is a library for a teensy FOOTPRINT, that is: you can plug an existing teensy in it, and make connections to it. You can not use it to MAKE a teensy.

Comment: Ahh, see I had no idea what a "footprint" was. Thanks, I guess this part isn't appropriate for me to use then.